# Hacer que en util.Random no se repitan valores dentro de un vector

Tags: java, bucle-for, random, vectores

No sé cómo hacer que no se repitan los valores, estoy haciendo un juego Bingo, así que es fundamental que no se repitan números. Está hecho con vectores, porque con Matrices se me hizo muy complicado conseguir lo que quise. Este es mi código.

````
public class Ran {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int min = 1;
        int max = 14;

        Random random = new Random();
                int bi[] = new int[5];
                int ipe[] = new int[5];
                int ng[] = new int[5];
                int go[] = new int[5];
                int oo[] = new int[5];

                 for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++){
                 bi[a] = random.nextInt(max + min) + min;
                 System.out.print("[" + bi[a] + "]");

                 ipe[a] = random.nextInt(max + min) + min + 15;
                 System.out.print("[" + ipe[a] + "]");

                 ng[a] = random.nextInt(max + min) + min + 30;
                 System.out.print("[" + ng[a] + "]");

                 go[a] = random.nextInt(max + min) + min + 45;
                 System.out.print("[" + go[a] + "]");

                 oo[a] = random.nextInt(max + min) + min + 60;
                 System.out.println("[" + oo[a] + "]");
                }
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo 3 opciones (y hay muchas más)

### Opción 1. Un algoritmo clásico

Genera un array con la secuencia de números (*en este caso creo que 1 a 14*) y desordénalo aleatoriamente. Si quieres 5 aleatorios sin repeticiones de esa secuencia, simplemente lee entonces desde la posición 0 a 4 de dicho array desordenado.

Te dejo una función de ejemplo que hace esto mismo, devolviendo una lista en lugar de un array normal. Puedes usarla para obtener una lista con la cantidad de números que vayas a usar, sin repeticiones, y de paso simplificar un poco tu código.

```java
public static List<Integer> aleatorios(int min, int max, int cantidad) {
    if (cantidad > max - min) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "No hay tantos números en el rango de " + min + " a " + max);
    }

    // Generar una secuencia de min a max
    ArrayList<Integer> conjunto = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = min; i <= max; i++) { conjunto.add(i); }

    // Desordenar
    Collections.shuffle(conjunto);

    // Devolver una lista con los primeros "cantidad" elementos
    // que serán aleatorios dado el desorden.
    return conjunto.subList(0, cantidad);
}
```

### Opción 2. Variación del anterior

En lugar de desordenar el array, simplemente selecciona una posición aleatoria entre 0 y su tamaño, entonces elimina el elemento. Necesitas un contenedor dinámico (ArrayList por ejemplo) para eliminar el nº. De esta forma nunca podrás volver a seleccionar dicho nº porque no existe en el array. Lo único que ahorra este proceso es el paso de desordenar a cambio de tener que borrar.

### Opción 3. Tener en cuenta los generados.

La opción que te sugiere Dramaturgo en su respuesta, pero usa HashSet en lugar de ArrayList como te sugiere. Los HashSet como toda colección, tienen un método `contains` que te indica si contiene un elemento concreto. La idea de usar HashSet es que su método contains es de complejidad O(1), mientras que el de ArrayList de complejidad O(n) (es menos eficiente a medida que tiene más elementos). En cualquier caso, esta opción es potencialmente la peor, dado que es "infinitamente" ineficiente al depender de la suerte constante (repetir la generación en bucle hasta generar uno que no haya sido generado previamente).

Comment: Las preguntas llevan un ejemplo mínimo verificable (esta lo tiene). Las respuestas idealmente deberían incluir información sobre cómo usar lo que sea que sugieres como respuesta.

Comment: @Alfabravo Gracias por el recordatorio tenía un ejemplo en borradores que creía ya había añadido. Añado solo el que considero más relevante, siéntete libre de extender mi respuesta con más ejemplos si lo consideras.

Comment: Es que me gusta mucho tu respuesta :P

Answer (score 0):

Puedes apoyarte en el uso de un `ArrayList` y su método [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) en el cual se agregara los valores generados aleatoriamente,y con el uso de un bucle `while` evaluaremos que si el `Arraylist` contiene un numero previamente guardado, se genere otro diferente aleatoriamente

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int min = 1;
        int max = 14;
        int aux=0;

         //Declaramos el ArrayList
        ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        Random random = new Random();
                int bi[] = new int[5];
                int ipe[] = new int[5];
                int ng[] = new int[5];
                int go[] = new int[5];
                int oo[] = new int[5];

               

         for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++){
            //Generamos un valor aleatoreo
            aux=random.nextInt(max + min) + min;
               while(lista.contains(aux)){//evaluamos si el array contiene,al ser el primer numero pasara a agregarse al ArrayList y asignarse a la primera posicion del primer array
                  aux=random.nextInt(max + min) + min;
               }  
                  lista.add(aux);
                  bi[a] =aux;
                  System.out.print(" ["+String.format("%3d",bi[a])+"] ");
            //lo mismo pero esta vez el valor aleatorio sera generado en un rango mayor,si generase el mismo numero aleatorio que el anterior,recuerda que ya esta agregado en el ArrayList, por ende si pasara eso nuestro bucle generario otro numero diferente     
            aux=random.nextInt(max + min) + min + 15;
                while(lista.contains(aux)){
                     aux=random.nextInt(max + min) + min;
               }  
                  lista.add(aux);
                  ipe[a] =aux;
                  System.out.print(" ["+String.format("%3d",ipe[a])+"] ");
                  
          //el resto es repetitivo........       
            aux=random.nextInt(max + min) + min + 30;
               while(lista.contains(aux)){
                     aux=random.nextInt(max + min) + min;
               }  
                  lista.add(aux);
                  ng[a] =aux;
                  System.out.print(" ["+String.format("%3d",ng[a])+"] ");
                
                
            aux=random.nextInt(max + min) + min + 45;
                while(lista.contains(aux)){
                     aux=random.nextInt(max + min) + min;
               }  
                  lista.add(aux);
                  go[a] =aux;
                  System.out.print(" ["+String.format("%3d",go[a])+"] ");
                
                
            aux=random.nextInt(max + min) + min + 60;
                while(lista.contains(aux)){
                     aux=random.nextInt(max + min) + min;
               }  
                  lista.add(aux);
                  oo[a] =aux;
                  System.out.print(" ["+String.format("%3d",oo[a])+"] ");

                  System.out.println("");
                }               
    }
}
```

salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]